# Invalidate intrinsic size of sub views when super view changes size

Tags: cocoa, interface-builder, autolayout

I'm creating my auto layout constraints programmatically.  My subview's width are set equal to their superview's width and have a flexible height based on their contents.

Is there a way to tell my subviews to invalidate their intrinsic size when the parent view changes size?  Right now I'm doing it manually in `-layout` but I feel like there should be an way an automatic way to handle this.

```
- (void)layout
{
    [super layout];

    NSArray *views = [self subviews];
    for(NSView *view in views)
    {
        [view invalidateIntrinsicContentSize];
    }
}
```